# Export a Pkcs10CertificationRequest object to a .pem file

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pem, pkcs#10

I have been testing Bouncy Castle in C#. I have not found a way to export a Pkcs10CertificationRequest object to a .pem file. I have tried with PemWriter objects but I have not succeeded. It can be the code or some idea of ​​how to do it. Can someone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what version of BC you are using, but at least in recent versions it is directly supported by PemWriter:

```
Pkcs10CertificationRequest pkcs10 = ...;
FileStream file = ...;

using (var w = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWriter(new StreamWriter(file)))
{
    w.WriteObject(pkcs10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I am using version 2.2.1. It wasn't working correctly for me because I was using the namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.  Shouldn't that work too? With Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl it works perfectly.